# SpriteKit - Adding a timer

Tags: ios, timer, sprite-kit

I'd like to add a timer to a simple SpriteKit game. Using the code suggested in an existing answer ("Spritekit - Creating a timer") causes 5 errors (s. comments below). Maybe there are other ideas, too!

Thanks a lot!

This is my .m file:

```
@implementation GameScene {
   BOOL updateLabel;    
   SKLabelNode *timerLabel;
}

int timer;

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

    timer = 0;

    updateLabel = false;

    timerLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    timerLabel.text = @"0";
    timerLabel.fontSize = 48;
    timerLabel.fontColor = [SKColor greenColor];
    timerLabel.position = CGPointMake(700,50);
    [self addChild: timerLabel];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

}
```

The following code gives me the trouble:

```
id wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0];//Redefinition of 'wait' as different kind of symbol
id run = [SKAction runBlock:^{//Initializer element is not a compile-time constant
    timer ++;
    updateLabel = true;
    }];
[node runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, run]]];//1. Expected identifier or '('; 2. Use of undeclared identifier 'node'; 3. Collection element of type 'pid_t (int *)' is not an Objective-C object


-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if(updateLabel == true){
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",timer];
    updateLabel = false;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int timer = 0;
SKLabelNode timerLabel;

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
SKAction *performSelector = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(timerLabel) onTarget:self];
SKAction *removeChild = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [timerLabel removeFromParent];
}];
SKAction *increaseTimer = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    timer++;
}];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[removeChild, performSelector, wait, increaseTimer]];
SKAction *repeat   = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
[self runAction:repeat];

}
return self;
}

-(void)timerLabel
{
    timerLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", timer];
    timerLabel.fontSize = 48;
    timerLabel.fontColor = [SKColor greenColor];
    timerLabel.position = CGPointMake(700,50);
    [self addChild: timerLabel];
}
```

Try to call with perform selector. I hope this will work.I didn't test.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but the following timerLabel overwrites the previous. At the end there is green spot. The time could't be read.